# How to add a column and convert dates in R

Tags: r

So I have the following data set which shows temperatures for 365 days of the year. Each date is labeled by the day of the week in a y-m-d format. I'm trying to add a new column called month, which will display the current month which the date shows. Ex: 2014-01-01 will show January while 2014-10-25 will show October. Can anyone help? I'm trying to use Lubridate, but I'm still new at R, and am having a lot of trouble.

Comment: No need for lubridate for something so simple - `x <- c("2014-01-01","2014-10-25"); format(as.Date(x),"%B")`

Comment: But x <- c("2014-01-01","2014-10-25") only works for those specific dates. How do I write it so that each of the 365 days will display the month?

Comment: Replace `x` with your column name, e.g. `dataset$datevar`. You'd probably benefit from reading 'An introduction to R' or taking a look at a tutorial site like http://statmethods.net/

Comment: If you must use `lubridate`, which you don't have to, you can use the incredibly cryptically named `month()` function, like `month(as.Date(x),label=TRUE,abbr=FALSE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `format.Date` function return a vector of character values and the "%B" parameter determine the result as full month values:

```
dfrm$Month <- format( as.Date(dfrm$yourDate) , "%B")
```

If yourDate-column were already an R Date-object then the `as.Date` is not needed. Consult the help page for strptime. There can be separators in between the (possibly multiple) format specs

```
 ?strptime
```